# example responses from proto openapiv2 specification

Tags: swagger, protocol-buffers, openapi

Say I have a rpc method as below

```
rpc RpcMethod(RpcRequest) returns (RpcResponse) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      get: "/rpcMethod"
      body: "*"
    };
    option (grpc.gateway.protoc_gen_openapiv2.options.openapiv2_operation) = {
      responses: {
        key: "200",
        value: {
          description: "OK";
          schema: {
            json_schema: {ref: ".rpc.RpcResponse"}
          }
        }
        examples : {TRYING_TO_FIGURE_OUT_HERE}
      };
    };
  }
```

For OpenAPI specification, I'm trying to create example responses to show as currently it just shows the RpcResponse struct in the generated SwaggerUI.
However is it not clear how the examples should be coded

```
message Response {
  // `Description` is a short description of the response.
  // GFM syntax can be used for rich text representation.
  string description = 1;
  // `Schema` optionally defines the structure of the response.
  // If `Schema` is not provided, it means there is no content to the response.
  Schema schema = 2;
  // `Headers` A list of headers that are sent with the response.
  // `Header` name is expected to be a string in the canonical format of the MIME header key
  // See: https://golang.org/pkg/net/textproto/#CanonicalMIMEHeaderKey
  map<string, Header> headers = 3;
  // `Examples` gives per-mimetype response examples.
  // See: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/3.0.0/versions/2.0.md#example-object
  map<string, string> examples = 4;
  // Custom properties that start with "x-" such as "x-foo" used to describe
  // extra functionality that is not covered by the standard OpenAPI Specification.
  // See: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/swagger-extensions/
  map<string, google.protobuf.Value> extensions = 5;
}
```

From the openapiv2.proto, there is an examples field, labeled with number 4 as shown above.
However I just can't get this field to work. Is it suppose to be not used, like some reserved fields?
The official documents and the associated github pages aren't quite helpful specifically with this certain case.
Would appreciate if someone can show me a workaround to this problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can add examples in `.rpc.RpcResponse` definition.
I added an example for the description field below:

```
import "protoc-gen-openapiv2/options/annotations.proto";

message Response {
    // `Description` is a short description of the response.
    // GFM syntax can be used for rich text representation.
    string description = 1 [(grpc.gateway.protoc_gen_openapiv2.options.openapiv2_field) = {
        example: "\"my description example\""
    }];
}
```